# non trivial involutary group isomorphism of (C*,x)

Tags: gr.group-theory

Hello,

I would like to know whether the only non trivial involutary group isomorphism $f:(\mathbb{C}^{*},\times)\to(\mathbb{C}^{*},\times)$ is the complex conjugation or not.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See ccc's answer here for a complete list of all (measurable) endomorphisms. You can easily check which ones of those are involutive: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52319/

Answer (score 2):

$z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Indeed...Maybe it's time for me to go to bed :/

Answer (score 1):

How about $$ z\mapsto \frac{z}{|z|^2}?$$